# Need help subtracting Hex: 0x120 - 0x8

Tags: hex

I'm working with memory locations in Hex and I'm having trouble subtracting two Hex numbers. I tried watching tutorials on YouTube and I'm still stuck.

My memory locations are  0x120, 0x 118, 0x110, 0x 108, 0x100
Subtracting 0x118-0x8 seems simple enough: 0x110

How do I subtract 0x120 - 0x8 ? I know the result is 0x118, but I'm not sure why.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple as follow ( 0x010 = 16 ):

```
0x120 - 0x8 =
    (0x110 + 0x010) - 0x008 =
    (0x110 + 0x008 + 0x008) - 0x008 =
    0x110 + 0x008 = 0x118.
```